# Android cannot find accessory device after enabling WiFi debugging

Tags: android, debugging, adk, accessory

I'm developing an Android Accessory using a Galaxy Nexus phone and the official [Arduino ADK](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardADK) board.  I'm using all the standard Arduino libraries available [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/adk.html).  I'd like to be able to debug my Android code at runtime so I followed Googles' instructions in their "[Debugging Considerations](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html)" documentation in order to do remote debugging via WiFi.

When I connect to the phone via USB I'm able to debug just fine (of course it's not talking to the Arduino board though).  When I connect to the phone via WiFi I can debug just fine.  However when I plug in the board to the phone it no longer auto-launches my application (that's registered with the ADK device).  So instead I manually start my application but it cannot find the Arduino accessory.  If I switch back to USB debugging and reconnect the ADK board to the phone it auto-launches like normal and everything is fine, but then I'm back to not being able to debug.

There are no changes to the code during all of this.  All I did was change how the adb tool reaches the phone.  Any guesses why the phone and my application can no longer see the ADK board?

In short:

1. If the phone is set to debug via USB, it can talk to the Arduino ADK with no problems.
2. If I invoke "adb tcpip 5555 < enter> adb connect < device-ip-address>:5555" I can remotely debug the phone with no problems.
3. If I now connect the ADK board to the phone with the USB cable, the phone cannot find the ADK board, but I can still do remote debugging via WiFi.  That's how I know that the accessory cannot be found.

Edit:
The phone is running Android 4.1.1 and the Arduino is 1.0.1.

Comment: I had issues where the connection to the USB accessory would be lost without apparent reason. On the log I could see "could not open /dev/usb_accessory". Turning off adb wifi fixed the problem. Of course, in order to debug the accessory I rely on a logcat app.

Answer (score 1):

Just bumped into this problem, having returned to USB Accessory work. Yes there is a problem, I've no idea how to fix the problem as later versions of Android simply don't allow you to both run adb over wifi and USB Accessory at the same time. My solution and you probably got there already yourself was to root my phone, luckily a Nexus S, and down grade the Android on it to 2.3.6

It's not a great solution but to debug USB Accessory I have to boot into 2.3.6. Hopefully in the future this might work again.

Comment: For other reasons I couldn't downgrade the device.  I was working on a very very very short term project just to demonstrate some potential capabilities. I didn't have time to keep investigating so I resorted to lots of logging statements on the phone's GUI. That's caveman style debugging, but it got the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging USB Accessory through wifi is only possible on **Nexus** devices. I tried many others (Samsung's, Motorola), they don't detect accessory when USB debugging is enabled in settings. Also tried hardware usb switcher - does not help.